# set the same gif as an icon in several JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gif

I want to set a gif (without loop, just plays once) as an icon of several JLabels (with setIcon). The problem is: when I set it as an icon of the first JLabel the gif plays in a normal way, but in the second and the others just stay at the last frame...

My question is: how can I make that gif plays as many times as I want, without interfering the past JLabels?

Hope I have made ​​my point.

EDIT:
I've tried using repaint() but still can't make it work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a small (in bytes) animated GIF that has a number of frames but only one loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the image as a `byte[]` and stamp it out as a separate image for each label.

The JRE normally caches image instances if loaded by `URL` or `File`, but providing a `byte[]` (or `ByteArrayInputStream`) to the loading method prevents caching.